# rvest click and action

Tags: r, scrape, rvest

I want to scrape the following site:

http://e-submit.crm.com.mk/AAOL/pCheckLeSize.aspx

The action that I need to do is fill the textbox and click the only button, to recieve one line of text.

Heres an example picture[image: scrape]

Any ideas how I can pull this off? I've scraped sites by changing the url, but the site is written in asp.net, and hides the url.

Comment: It's a SharePoint-backed site with a pretty large viewstate. You'll need to use something like RSelenium to fill in the box, press the button and scrape the text. It'll be virtually impossible to just replicate the XHR request in any programming language.

Comment: thank you for the library hint